# auth 0 password confirmation template

Tags: go, authentication, server, oauth, auth0

I am using AUTH 0 server . and I am new to this one. I need passwords confirmation template and in this template a URL field is defined. but I didn't get , where the URL value is defined.

Please check the images attached. while calling the email verification end point the template is mailed in to the mail. but the if we redirect to the URL filed it shows blank.

where I can identify the value of URL and its template design

Please help me

in the 3rd image , I am asking about the {{url}}
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: url]

Answer (score 0):

The value for `{{url}}` is just a placeholder - the value comes from Auth0, but AFAIK you can't change the value of this variable. If you want a different URL in your email template, you could just remove '{{url}}' and replace it with any hard coded value.

In your example template above, the email that gets sent to the user will have a "Confirm my account" hyperlink with a href value to whatever the value of `{{url}}` was substituted with (as mentioned the value comes from Auth0).

When you click on the link, it will go to your Auth0 tenant and update `email_verified` to true for the specific user clicking on the link. Auth0 will then return a HTTP 3XX redirect response (302 from memory) with a location header of whatever you set as the "Redirect To" field in the email template.